# What is latest version joi-browser and its name if it is changed?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, joi

What is latest version of npm validation package `joi-browser`? I have searched alot and unfortunately I found nothing clear info about it.

I found `@hapi/joi, v17.1.x` and I guess which is only for Nodejs, also Joi left **@Hapi** Organization so its name is changed. I found `joi-browser v13.x.x` which is **2-3 years old**.
I want to use Joi for frontend(React) so what is latest version of Joi for frontend and what is its exact name if it is changed?

Comment: Deprecation Notice: @hapi/joi@16.0.0 now has direct browser support.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like joi-browser has been deprecated. As of v16.0.0 of joi, it now includes browser support as you can see here: https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2037

Comment: Please consider adding this as a comment instead of a comment. Note: @maverick has already pointed out a **possible** solution.